# Inexplicable free(): invalid size in delete[] in C++

Tags: c++, memory, delete-operator

I use the exact same 2d array (it's a field of the class) in both cases. The second one `lsh_distances` won't let me delete[] the inner 1d arrays in the destructor and gives an error of `free(): invalid size Aborted (core dumped)`. If I don't use the for-loop to delete[] the inner arrays I of course have a memory leak (checked with valgrind).

Why one earth is this happening? it makes no sense. I don't delete `lsh_distances` anywhere else, I can actually print the values in the destructor.

HELP

Here is the code.

```
long long int NearestNeighboursSearch::calculate_exact_distances() {
    unsigned int q_size = query_dataset.points.size();
    unsigned int ind_size = index_dataset.points.size();
    exact_distances = new long double*[q_size];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < q_size ; i++) {
        exact_distances[i] = new long double[ind_size];
    }
    chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < q_size ; i++) {
        for (int j = 0 ; j < ind_size ; j++) {
            exact_distances[i][j] = used_distance(*query_dataset.points.at(i), *index_dataset.points.at(j));
        }
    }
    chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    return chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(end - begin).count();
}

long long int NearestNeighboursSearch::calculate_lsh_distances() {
    unsigned int q_size = query_dataset.points.size();
    unsigned int ind_size = index_dataset.points.size();
    lsh_distances = new long double*[q_size];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < q_size ; i++) {
        lsh_distances[i] = new long double[ind_size];
        for (int j = 0 ; j < ind_size ; j++) {
            lsh_distances[i][j] = -1.0;   // not calculated
        }
    }
    // calculate and fill only distances between points that hash into the same bucket for the L hash tables
    chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < q_size ; i++) {
        Point *p1 = query_dataset.points.at(i);
        Bucket **buckets = index_dataset.get_buckets_for_point(p1);   // L buckets
        for (int j = 0 ; j < index_dataset.get_hashtables_count(); j++) {
            for (int k = 0 ; k < buckets[j]->points.size() ; k++) {           // might be empty
                const Point *p2 = buckets[j]->points[k];
                // update appropriate distance at [i, p2->pos]
                lsh_distances[i][p2->pos] = used_distance(*p1, *p2);
            }
        }
        delete[] buckets;
    }
    chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    return chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(end - begin).count();
}

NearestNeighboursSearch::~NearestNeighboursSearch() {
    if (exact_distances != NULL) {
        for (int i = 0; i < query_dataset.points.size(); i++) {
            delete[] exact_distances[i];
        }
        delete[] exact_distances;
    }
    if (lsh_distances != NULL) {
        // TODO: Somehow this causes an error (it makes no sense to me)
        for (int i = 0; i < query_dataset.points.size(); i++) {
            delete[] lsh_distances[i];
        }
        delete[] lsh_distances;
    }
}
```

Edit: I did a run with valgrind as per a suggestion. I got this:

```
==376== Invalid write of size 4
==376==    at 0x11508A: NearestNeighboursSearch::calculate_lsh_distances() (neighbour_search.cpp:66)
==376==    by 0x10B2CA: main (lsh_main.cpp:132)
==376==  Address 0x4e385c0 is 16 bytes before a block of size 160 alloc'd
==376==    at 0x483C583: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==376==    by 0x114F17: NearestNeighboursSearch::calculate_lsh_distances() (neighbour_search.cpp:52)
==376==    by 0x10B2CA: main (lsh_main.cpp:132)
==376==
==376== Invalid write of size 2
==376==    at 0x11508A: NearestNeighboursSearch::calculate_lsh_distances() (neighbour_search.cpp:66)
==376==    by 0x10B2CA: main (lsh_main.cpp:132)
==376==  Address 0x4e385c8 is 8 bytes before a block of size 160 alloc'd
==376==    at 0x483C583: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==376==    by 0x114F17: NearestNeighboursSearch::calculate_lsh_distances() (neighbour_search.cpp:52)
==376==    by 0x10B2CA: main (lsh_main.cpp:132)
==376==
```

I will investigate this... It seems that p2->pos is < 0 somehow.

Comment: Please create a [mcve].  Crashes like this often result from writing out of bounds in some other part of the program, and the easiest way for someone to find it will be to compile and run an actual test case, possibly with tools such as AddressSanitizer or valgrind.  You should also try these tools yourself if you haven't.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I figured out why thanks to the comment and valgrind. `p2->pos` was `-1` after a careless mistake somewhere else and I was overwritting something important probably. Logic restored.